# Android capture full image with camera

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am following this tutorial for getting full size image from camera: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

When I test this I get "this device has a camera":

```
if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        Log.i(TAG, " this device has a camera " );
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        Log.i(TAG, " no camera on this device " );

    }
```

However when I try this cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager() is null:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   
               if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.i(TAG, "IOException");
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.i(TAG, " cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager null " );

                }
```

I have all this in my manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="aptean.com.routesetter.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

and my file_paths.xml file in xml folder:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/aptean.com.routesetter/files/Pictures" />
```

Comment: On Android 11 you should not try to resolve.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed explanation? What does it mean? Remove this if statement or use different approach?

Comment: Do not try to resolve first. Thats all. What's unclear about that?

Comment: 1. So I need to remove if statement? 2. What about user with older Android version?

Comment: Just catch the application not found or whatever it is named exception and you are done for all versions. Or check sdk int to resolve or not.

Comment: Strange is that you still did not tell if you can launch the intent if you do not try to resolve.

Comment: Yes, I can launch intent without resolve.